font harmonization with ggsurvplot pdf export
I am having some trouble getting my plots to look presentable. Here is what I am struggling with:

*see below for minimal example used to generate the above mess.
Never mind the legend block overlapping the plot. With my real data it isn't a problem. What I would like is for the y- and x-axis titles of the survival plot and at risk table to be the same. I also want the fonts the same size for the x- and y-axis ticks, and "groups" of the Legend to be the same font size as "Number at risk". How to set the font size of the numbers in the risk table would be nice too. I know how to manipulate the font sizes of the survival plot and legend but can't get useful info on how to manipulate the legend table.
I have trawled the internet looking for information to set the font sizes of the risk table without success. Any advice would be much appreciated.
Minimal Example:
library(survival)
library(survminer)
library(gtsummary)
library(dplyr)

data(ovarian)
data

ggsurv <- ggsurvplot(
    fit = survfit(Surv(futime, fustat) ~ rx, data = ovarian), ggtheme = theme_classic2(base_family = "Helvetica"),
    xlab = "days survived", 
break.y.by = 0.1,
break.x.by = 100,
    ylab = "Overall survival probability",
    size = 0.5, censor.size=5,
    legend = c(0.80,0.85), legend.title = "groups", legend.labs = c("control", "treatment"), font.legend = c(10, "plain", "black"),
    risk.table = TRUE,
risk.table.fontsize = 2,
    conf.int = TRUE,
log.rank.weights = "1", pval.method = TRUE, pval.method.coord = c(0, 0.2),
           pval.method.size = 3,
    pval = TRUE, pval.size = 3,
pval.coord = c(0,0.1),
font.tickslab =c(6, "plain", "black"),
font.x =c(8, "plain", "black"),
font.y =c(8, "plain", "black"),
surv.median.line = "hv",
tables.height = 0.35
)
ggsurv

pdf("minexample.pdf",onefile=FALSE,
width = 3.5, height = 3)
ggsurv
dev.off()

